# Grails application behind https

Tags: grails, deployment, https

I've been playing with Grails for few months and I've just build my first app. Can someone tell me how to put my grails application behind https? I used Grails 1.3.7, Spring Security Core 1.2.7.2 and deployed it on Tomcat 7. If you need more info please say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using Tomcat you'll need to install an SSL cert for Tomcat.  The details of that process are too lengthly, IMHO, for SO.  Especially when the information is readily available on the web:

[Install SSL Cert](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-tomcat.htm)

You can also run it locally during dev in https mode by appending -https to your run-app command.

Comment: Thanks Gregg. I will research Tomcat SSL.